# How best can I Design my Model class

Tags: .net, wpf, c#-4.0, mvvm, models

I have a WPF application, and I am a bit new to it. Pretty much done with designing the Views and the ViewModels. Stuck at designing the Model class, which I intend to use as a layer that gives me the required data by connecting to the Database.

Suppose I have a Grid that displays the Customer details. I thought of writing something like blow:

```
class CustomerModel
    {
        public DataView GetCustomerData()
        {
            // Fetch the data from Database and prepare a Dataview
            // return the DataView
        }
    }
```

My problems are

- If I am displaying all the Customer Data, then the above method would suffice. But, what if I have a filter option on the GUI for the Grid, shoud I write a separate function that gets me the Data based on the Filter parameters? (Probably overload the function to accommodate filter parameters)
- Also, suppose I have 10 Grids that require data from various tables each. Will I have to write 10 such different classes? (Like `CustomerModel`, `OrderModel`, `EmployeeModel`.etc)

Could you please let me know how best can I tackle with the Model component?

Answer (score 0):

> If I am displaying all the Customer Data, then the above method would suffice. But, what if I have a filter option on the GUI for the Grid, shoud I write a separate function that gets me the Data based on the Filter parameters? (Probably overload the function to accommodate filter parameters)

Separate your data access logic from the model and use a `Command` to access the logic (look for the `async` `await` pattern to avoid freezing your UI) and fill your model. You could use a [`ListCollectionView`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.listcollectionview(v=vs.110).aspx) as your DataGrids `ItemSource`  to easily add filtering and sorting functionality.

> Also, suppose I have 10 Grids that require data from various tables each. Will I have to write 10 such different classes? (Like CustomerModel, OrderModel, EmployeeModel.etc)

Depends on what you´re planning to do, but I think it´d make sense to have different models for each purpose. You can put conformities in basic properties together (e.g. `CustomerModel` has a `Contact`-property of type `PersonModel` and so you can add a `PersonalData`-property with the same type to your `EmployeeModel`)

Just ask, if you need more details, or something is not clear.